# MD5 - shift function

Tags: cryptography, md5

I try to understand MD5 algorithm. I found on the wikipedia a pseudocode. This is a fragment:

```
//Main loop:
for i from 0 to 63
    if 0 ≤ i ≤ 15 then
        F := (B and C) or ((not B) and D)
        g := i
    else if 16 ≤ i ≤ 31
        F := (D and B) or ((not D) and C)
        g := (5×i + 1) mod 16
    else if 32 ≤ i ≤ 47
        F := B xor C xor D
        g := (3×i + 5) mod 16
    else if 48 ≤ i ≤ 63
        F := C xor (B or (not D))
        g := (7×i) mod 16
    dTemp := D
    D := C
    C := B
    B := B + leftrotate((A + F + K[i] + M[g]), s[i])
    A := dTemp
end for
```

I almost understand it but I'm wondering what's stored in **g** variable?

Comment: Yes, I know. But I dont' understand what's means: (5*i + 1) mod 16, (3×i + 5) mod 16 and (7×i) mod 16 ...

Comment: You don't understand me. I know it all... I want only understand what determines of this index value.

Comment: How could it be more clear? The index value is a function of `i`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wikipedia states:

> "The processing of a message block consists of four similar stages, termed rounds; each round is composed of 16 similar operations". From the pseudo code it can be seen that each round the parts of the message, denoted by `M`, are mixed in at a different time of the round.

The function to generate `g` - an index into the message block - will make sure that each part of the message is mixed in. 5, 3 and 7 are all primes and of course they don't have a common divisor with each other or 16. That means that, together with the initial offsets 1, 5 and 0 they make sure that the distribution is as dissimilar as possible.

The index `i` goes from 0 to 63, which is 4 x 16 - 1. This makes sure that all the parts of the message are mixed in once, at each of the rounds.

**EDIT**: I thought that the initial g = i could generate an index out of bounds, but that code is only executed for i in the range 0..15 so the % 16 can indeed be left out.

---

Below is an "unrolled" (meaning all the loops have been written out) implementation of the inner structure of MD5. Here you can see how `g` operates on the `in` array:

```
/* Basic MD5 step. Transform buf based on in.
 */
static void Transform (buf, in)
UINT4 *buf;
UINT4 *in;
{
  UINT4 a = buf[0], b = buf[1], c = buf[2], d = buf[3];

  /* Round 1 */
#define S11 7
#define S12 12
#define S13 17
#define S14 22
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[ 0], S11, 3614090360); /* 1 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[ 1], S12, 3905402710); /* 2 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[ 2], S13,  606105819); /* 3 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[ 3], S14, 3250441966); /* 4 */
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[ 4], S11, 4118548399); /* 5 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[ 5], S12, 1200080426); /* 6 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[ 6], S13, 2821735955); /* 7 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[ 7], S14, 4249261313); /* 8 */
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[ 8], S11, 1770035416); /* 9 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[ 9], S12, 2336552879); /* 10 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[10], S13, 4294925233); /* 11 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[11], S14, 2304563134); /* 12 */
  FF ( a, b, c, d, in[12], S11, 1804603682); /* 13 */
  FF ( d, a, b, c, in[13], S12, 4254626195); /* 14 */
  FF ( c, d, a, b, in[14], S13, 2792965006); /* 15 */
  FF ( b, c, d, a, in[15], S14, 1236535329); /* 16 */

  /* Round 2 */
#define S21 5
#define S22 9
#define S23 14
#define S24 20
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[ 1], S21, 4129170786); /* 17 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[ 6], S22, 3225465664); /* 18 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[11], S23,  643717713); /* 19 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[ 0], S24, 3921069994); /* 20 */
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[ 5], S21, 3593408605); /* 21 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[10], S22,   38016083); /* 22 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[15], S23, 3634488961); /* 23 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[ 4], S24, 3889429448); /* 24 */
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[ 9], S21,  568446438); /* 25 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[14], S22, 3275163606); /* 26 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[ 3], S23, 4107603335); /* 27 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[ 8], S24, 1163531501); /* 28 */
  GG ( a, b, c, d, in[13], S21, 2850285829); /* 29 */
  GG ( d, a, b, c, in[ 2], S22, 4243563512); /* 30 */
  GG ( c, d, a, b, in[ 7], S23, 1735328473); /* 31 */
  GG ( b, c, d, a, in[12], S24, 2368359562); /* 32 */

  /* Round 3 */
#define S31 4
#define S32 11
#define S33 16
#define S34 23
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[ 5], S31, 4294588738); /* 33 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[ 8], S32, 2272392833); /* 34 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[11], S33, 1839030562); /* 35 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[14], S34, 4259657740); /* 36 */
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[ 1], S31, 2763975236); /* 37 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[ 4], S32, 1272893353); /* 38 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[ 7], S33, 4139469664); /* 39 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[10], S34, 3200236656); /* 40 */
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[13], S31,  681279174); /* 41 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[ 0], S32, 3936430074); /* 42 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[ 3], S33, 3572445317); /* 43 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[ 6], S34,   76029189); /* 44 */
  HH ( a, b, c, d, in[ 9], S31, 3654602809); /* 45 */
  HH ( d, a, b, c, in[12], S32, 3873151461); /* 46 */
  HH ( c, d, a, b, in[15], S33,  530742520); /* 47 */
  HH ( b, c, d, a, in[ 2], S34, 3299628645); /* 48 */

  /* Round 4 */
#define S41 6
#define S42 10
#define S43 15
#define S44 21
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[ 0], S41, 4096336452); /* 49 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[ 7], S42, 1126891415); /* 50 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[14], S43, 2878612391); /* 51 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[ 5], S44, 4237533241); /* 52 */
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[12], S41, 1700485571); /* 53 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[ 3], S42, 2399980690); /* 54 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[10], S43, 4293915773); /* 55 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[ 1], S44, 2240044497); /* 56 */
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[ 8], S41, 1873313359); /* 57 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[15], S42, 4264355552); /* 58 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[ 6], S43, 2734768916); /* 59 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[13], S44, 1309151649); /* 60 */
  II ( a, b, c, d, in[ 4], S41, 4149444226); /* 61 */
  II ( d, a, b, c, in[11], S42, 3174756917); /* 62 */
  II ( c, d, a, b, in[ 2], S43,  718787259); /* 63 */
  II ( b, c, d, a, in[ 9], S44, 3951481745); /* 64 */

  buf[0] += a;
  buf[1] += b;
  buf[2] += c;
  buf[3] += d;
}
```